# Upgrading to Always Encrypted on SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, encryption

We are wanting to upgrade from column level encryption on SQL Server 2012 to always encrypted for its improved security. When I look up Always Encrypted compatibility, SQL Server 2012 is not included.

However, when I look up the ODBC driver, which apparently allows always encrypted to function, the driver says that it can allow certain 2016 features to work on SQL Server 2012.

Is there a way to make always encrypted work on SQL Server 2012?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to make always encrypted work on 2012 Server?

No. AlwaysEncrypted was a new feature added in [SQL Server 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/what-s-new-in-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-2016)